# How to convert 24 Hours format to 12 Hours format using DAX Function / Advance editor data type conversion Using Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm receiving time in 24 hours format from Database but we need to convert that into 12 hours for some calculation purpose. how to convert the same in power bi

ex.

```
10 --> 10:00:00 AM 

22 --> 10:00:00 PM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Advanced editor right-click the column and select change type and then select time then the result would be 10:00:00 AM for 10 and 10:00:00 PM for 22.

[image]

Another way is use **TIME()** function in DAX query

```
TIME("10") --> 10:00:00 AM
TIME("22") --> 10:00:00 PM
```